# How can NLTK work centrally on a MacBook?

Tags: python, pip, nltk, macos-mojave

I installed NLTK on my Macbook with MacOS Mojave on the 
`/usr/local/share/nltk_data all` 
directory.

I've installed it using

```
sudo pip install -U nltk
```

and then

```
sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all
```

But I cannot access NLTK from python from any other directory.

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
from nltk.collocations import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 38, in <module>
from nltk.util import ngrams
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/util.py", line 10, in <module>
import inspect
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
import tokenize
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 31, in <module>
from token import *
File "token.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
from nltk.tokenize.mwe import MWETokenizer
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/mwe.py", line 31, in <module>
from nltk.util import Trie
ImportError: cannot import name Trie`
```

I get that error on Python 2.7. On Python3, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>         
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

NLTK only works if I try to call if from within the 'nltk_data' folder where I installed it. I want to access it from everywhere.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Ok... first thing, you've installed nltk in your python 2.7 installation. Therefore, it will not work with python3 or any other version. Second, python 2.7 is soon to [reach end of life](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0466/). Third, nltk (and most other python packages) are best installed in a virtualenv -- why do you want it globally?

Comment: I suggest you do `sudo pip3 install nltk` and then import it from python3 and see if it works.

Comment: I should've done it on an environment. It struck me AFTER i did the installation. I installed it with pip and pip3. I wanted it globally just to access nltk from other folders as well, instead of only the nltk_data folder @hd1

Comment: I did install it with pip3. Still, it only works in the nltk_data folder @omeanwell

Comment: @BhaskarGhosh you could also try `sudo -H pip3 install nltk`

Comment: Do you want to put that in as an answer please?

Comment: I have nltk installed on my system in a virtualenv. I access it using the python interpreter at /Users/hd1/.virtualenvs/data/bin/python3 with the nltk_data directory under the same venv. Needing only to specify the correct interpreter when I use it. Perhaps this will work for you?

Comment: Did you have to enter the data directory each time you have to use nltk? Or could you access nltk from anywhere inside the venv?

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: No IDE yet. Was trying the terminal. I use Atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo -H pip3 install nltk --force-reinstall` this should work

Comment: Hey, I get the error

    Requirement already satisfied: nltk in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.4)
    Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (1.12.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (3.4.0.3)
    You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.

Comment: Try `sudo -H pip3 install nltk --force-reinstall`